How to Enable Windows Subsystem of Linux in Windows 11
Out of the box, Windows 11 recognizes the wsl command exists. However, it does not take me anywhere except show me info about flags for wsl --install:
First, I did the following to avoid unecessarily installing bloat onto the new system:

Opened PowerShell as administrator.
Ran the following command:


PS C:\Users\User> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux.


Restarted the laptop.

Hoping that now the wsl command would work. Alas, it was the same as before.  Running wsl --install showed me a list of 14 options of distro.
I ran the following on powershell.exe:

PS C:\Users\User> wsl --install -d Ubuntu

And got:

An error occurred during installation. Distribution Name: 'Ubuntu' Error Code: 0x8000ffff

I searched the error code and it could be an issue with 1. The update component (whatever that is) or 2. with a 3rd party software like the McAfee Antivirus I have.

Background: - Why am I trying to enable wsl?

Run ROS2 to set up communication between the laptop and a controller board
To verify the answer on my previous question regarding text merging


Now, what am I expected to do?
EDIT (27/8/24):
Following the answer, here is what I proceeded to do:
First, I installed WSL from the MS Store. In future, I may try to do with winget or locate the full wsl.exe from an internet search.
Finally, I ran the command without the -d flag and got the following (verbatim):

PS C:\Users\User\Documents> wsl --install Ubuntu
Ubuntu is already installed.
Launching Ubuntu...
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
Please create a default UNIX user account. The username does not need to match your Windows username.
For more information visit: https://aka.ms/wslusers
Enter new UNIX username: user
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: password updated successfully
The operation completed successfully.
Installation successful!
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo ".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)


 * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage



This message is shown once a day. To disable it please create the
/home/user/.hushlogin file.

HENCE, THE INSTALLATION WAS A SUCCESS THANKS TO SUPERUSER. Thank you to everyone who made this possible. I hope every issue troubleshoot goes just as smoothly. Best wishes!

The only command you should be running to install WSL is wsl --install, otherwise, you’re not following the instructions to install it. Try the following method here to install WSL

First, and probably most important, there's no wsl --install -d option.  It's just wsl --install <distro>, where the distro is optional.  Ubuntu is the default.
But also:

First, I did the following to avoid unecessarily installing bloat onto the new system:

There's noting in the wsl --install command that is "bloat".  On the other hand, the Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature command you ran did install "bloat" by putting an outdated (and incomplete) version of WSL on your system.
For the purposes of your question, you can consider there to be three different versions of the wsl.exe commandline:

Out-of-the-box, as you've noticed, there is a "stub" wsl.exe that handles installation and not much more.

There's an older version of wsl.exe that was a Windows Optional Feature.  However, that hasn't been the case for a few years now. This version still had other dependencies for WSL2, so you almost certainly don't have a functioning WSL2 installation - Just WSL1. While you might be okay with that, keep in mind that WSL1 hasn't, as far as I can tell, been updated in several years, even to fix some serious bugs that broke 22.04 pretty badly.  All development appears to be in WSL2 alone.
Note: In your given state, it's likely that WSL1 is now set to be the default version for new distribution installs.  After install Ubuntu, please make sure to check what WSL version it is running under, using wsl -l -v.

Today, and for the last several years, the main WSL functionality is included in an App/Package that is usually installed from the Microsoft Store. This wsl.exe both functions as a commandline interface to WSL as well as the installer for additional distributions.  The wsl --install command takes care of enabling the right components as well as installing both WSL and the default distribution from the Store.


As Ramhound mentioned in the comments, the command that you are looking for is simply wsl --install.

Thank you for reciprocating in a clear and elucidating manner. I have noted the erroneous -d flag and am thrilled to have learned more about wsl in the process.
